# Can't Create Azure VM - A lease conflict occurred with the blob https://blah

Tags: azure

I used to have a VM called Blah2. It got lost when my Azure Trial expired. However there seems to be a residual storage blob.

I am now trying to create a VM called Blah3 and getting this error:

```
A lease conflict occurred with the blob https://portalvhds1k47j3l46kf3b.blob.core.windows.net/vhds. The long running operation tracking ID was: a27ca5fe937ac471a2c37d1d4589d902.
```

I could understand this if I was trying to create a VM with the same name.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You need to contact Azure support to resolve this.

Comment: Did you take a lease manually on the vhds container by any chance. That would cause this error too.